# VBA code example on Microsoft's website destroyed the clipboard for the rest of the computer. Why did this happen and how can I prevent it?

Tags: vba, ms-access, operating-system, windows-10, clipboard

This is something I didn't think was even possible, but here goes. I was trying to learn how to use the Windows API in Visual Basic to use system calls, and [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard) (yes, I had to type out the link manually to ask this question, more on that later) showed me how to use the clipboard to retrieve text that the user copied with `Ctrl+C`. Out of curiosity, and under the assumption that all user input is bad input, I tried pressing Print Screen and then running the code just to see what would happen. I got some error message (can't remember what) but what's very strange is, now the clipboard no longer works! Any attempt I make to paste after a cut or copy, no matter what program I'm using, either does nothing or returns an error message in the program I'm using it in. Yes, it's my fault for intentionally trying to break the code example, but let's be honest - there's no excuse for the OS to fall apart so easily. If it matters, I'm using a PC running Windows 10.

EDIT: Settings won't let me clear the clipboard, and when I try to view the clipboard history, it shows nothing is there. Unfortunately I wasn't able to screenshot the clipboard history because it closes by itself when I try to open Snipping Tool.
[image]

Comment: Hopefully not a dumb question, but have you rebooted? That should clear the problem.

Comment: @Andre I also agree with you. It's not a dumb question. Restarting the PC will clear the clipboard.

Comment: For the record, I also use this function ClipBoard_GetData(), and yes, it does funny things if the clipboard contains e.g. a bitmap, not text. But running `ClipBoard_SetData("foo")` fixes it. You can find a version [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard) at the bottom ("Copy To Clipboard With Windows API").

Comment: Make sure to always close the clipboard after opening it. Ensure it with On Error Goto, so that will closed, even when an error occurs.

Comment: I don't know about the VBA code, but since you're on Windows 10, try pressing just the `ins`/`prt sc`/`print screen` key (don't hold the `win`/`fn` key down). It should save the screenshot in OneDrive if you have it set up, and try keeping "Clipboard History" on, and you should be able to see the history in the Clipboard GUI when you press `Win + V`.

Comment: I did reboot and that fixed it. I figured it would, but what I should have made more clear is that I want to know why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've missed a `CloseClipboard()`, keeping the clipboard locked since Windows thinks a program is reading to it or writing from it. This will prevent other programs from working with the clipboard, since only one program can access it at a time. If Access is still open, you can try running `CloseClipboard` in the immediate window, else, I recommend a reboot.

On code like this, always add an error handler that calls `CloseClipboard()` to prevent leaving the clipboard open if something unexpected happens. Note that when working with WinAPI, you might encounter hard crashes that may not call the error handler, so always triple-check your pointers and expect crashes and reboots.

The code you've found is also not adjusted for 64-bit use, so beware. If you've got it to work by just slapping `PtrSafe` on the functions, you may end up with invalid pointers which can crash Access, leaving the clipboard open and unusable.

The code you've found, while written by Microsoft, is not of particularly good quality. I recommend first checking if there's text on the clipboard using [EnumClipboardFormats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumclipboardformats), then only requesting text if there actually is text on the clipboard.

Beware that using WinAPI through VBA is tough, it's not beginner stuff, especially regarding the clipboard.

Note that *there's no excuse for the OS to fall apart so easily* is not the attitude to have when working with WinAPI. You're directly interfacing with the OS without any of the securities that managed languages offer, and manually working with pointers. It can and will break if you do something invalid. There's a reason most people use libraries that abstract the dangerous stuff away, if you don't, all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

similar problem for me. I did not have a CloseClipboard() but when I looked in another module there was already a EmptyClipboard() so used that before the DupRec() call at each instance and no more problems with clipboard.  just FYI